# Efficient way to replace parts of a word in a document where the replacement words are defined in a excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I have a .txt file which is huge
I have read it using `readlines()` in python

Sample:

`lines = ["XX_A_Name, A_Bad_Joke = '67' , \n", "A quick Black.Jack fox JJ_Value over XX_A_Name a.lazy.dog\n"]`

Replacements are defined in excel file:

```
OldName    New_replacement
XX_A_        ZZ_B_
A_Bad_Joke   C_Good_Joke
Black.Jack   Yellow.flower
JJ_Value     KK_Sum
a.lazy.dog   very.huge
```

I want to read the excel file and replace all the occurances of the values which are listed in OldName column from the txt file.

For eg: the sample output should be like:

`["ZZ_B_Name, C_Good_Joke = '67' , \n",  "A quick Yellow.flower fox KK_Sum over ZZ_B_Name very.huge\n"]`

I want to create a function for this. because this is just sample portion of the txt file I've pasted here. there are multiple .txt files which has to be load, replaced and saved as a new .txt file.

I am seeking help for a efficient and a quick way to do this.

Reading excel can be done using `pd.read_excel()` and `re` package can be used for replace(). but I am not able to understand how everything will fit together.

Comment: When you say "replaced and saved as a new .txt file" do you mean a newly named file or do you want to rewrite the old file?

Comment: @CtrlZ Save a new file

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a spreadsheet with the replacement values in the A & B columns. The first row is irrelevant.

For each original document, create a new file with the original document name prefixed by "new_".

Iterate over the input document calling str.replace as many time as determined by the size of the list of replacements. This may not be the most efficient mechanism but it's functionally correct.

```
import openpyxl

# list of documents to process
document_list = ["Document.txt"]

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Replacements.xlsx")

replacements = []

for A, B, *_ in wb.active.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
    # clean up any leading/trailing whitespace
    replacements.append((A.strip(), B.strip()))

for file in document_list:
    with open(file) as data_in, open("new_"+file, "w") as data_out:
        for line in data_in:
            for r in replacements:
                line = line.replace(*r)
            data_out.write(line)
```

Comment: I would suggest OP to also look at pandas.read_excel(...), since pandas is more widely used than openpyxl and will have correspondingly more resources on the web. Does openpyxl have any particular advantages over pandas?

Comment: @butterflyknife There's a whole learning curve for Pandas. For this trivial case I felt that openpyxl was simple, effective and therefore appropriate

Comment: @CtrlZ I was trying to implement it using Pandas only. Are there any advantages of using openpyxl?

Comment: @ShubhamR The advantage is that my answer provides a working solution whereas your code (which you've chosen not to share) doesn't

Answer (score 0):

An answer using pandas.

```
# Load replacements from Excel.
# The path and sheet_name obviously need to be changed.
df_replacements = pd.read_excel(f"./data/{EXCEL_FILENAME}", sheet_name='so')

# Define the function to replace text in a line given the rows of a pandas dataframe.
def replace(line:str, df:pd.DataFrame):
    out_line = line
    for idx, row in df_replacements.iterrows():
        out_line = out_line.replace(row["OldName"], row["New_replacement"]) # Note that module `re` is not required for simple replacements.
    return out_line

# Loop through the original lines and make replacements.
out_lines = []
for line in lines:
    out_lines.append(replace(line, df_replacements))
        
out_lines
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you just use str.replace() method. If you have a .txt file with these words then you can define a function like this:

```
def replaceWords(text):
    replacements_df = df.read_excel('your_excel_file.xlsx')
    for index, row in replacements_df.iterrows():
      if row["OldName"] in text:
        text.replace(row["OldName"], row["New_replacement])
return text
```

Then you can use this function in this way:

```
new_text = ""
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    texts = f.readlines()
for text in texts:    
    new_text += replaceWords(text)
    new_text+= "\n"
```

If you have a large number of text files, this is probably going to take a while, so I would suggest you use multiprocessing to run a few of the text files at the same time and save them at a local device. For example:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool

def replaceWords(text):
    replacements_df = df.read_excel('your_excel_file.xlsx')
    for index, row in replacements_df.iterrows():
      if row["OldName"] in text:
        text.replace(row["OldName"], row["New_replacement"])
return text

def processText(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        texts = f.readlines()
    new_text = ""
    for text in texts:
        new_text += replaceWords(text)
        new_text += "\n"
    new_filepath = "new"+file_path #you may need to modify this appropriately
    with open(new_filepath, "wb") as f:
        f.write(new_text) 
    return new_text #optional

def process_texts_in_batches(file_paths):
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        results = pool.map(process_text, file_paths)
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_paths = os.listdir("path/to/rootdir") #basically the folder where you're keeping all the txt files
    results = process_texts_in_batches(file_paths)
```

Comment: Please validate your code before posting it as an answer